# Solving equation for X with given interval

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question "Solve each equation for $X$ in the interval $0\leq X\leq360^{\circ}$. Give your answer to 1 decimal place where appropriate."

The equation is $\cos(X-60^{\circ}) = 0.6$,

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Using the cast diagram I get $X = 113.1^{\circ}$ and $366.9^{\circ}$,

However, the solutions say that $X = 6.9^{\circ}$ and $113.1^{\circ}$,

What have I done wrong because this makes no sense to me.

Comment: What happens to result if you add $360 + 6.9$-degrees? Clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos y=\cos (y-360^o)$ for any $y$. Therefore  $\cos (366.9^o-60^o))=\cos (366.9^o-60^o-360^0)=\cos (6.9^o-60^o)$. You were asked for values only in the range $0^0$ to $360^0$.